# Issues installing ruby gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rubygems, rvm

I am trying to install bundler using ruby gems and RVM, but I am running into this error when I run the `bundle init` command:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 13 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/CalebKleveter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3:/Users/CalebKleveter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /Users/CalebKleveter/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

I am installing it using this command:

```
gem install --user-install bundler
```

I was having issues before when downloading bundler. I was getting this error:

```
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/CalebKleveter/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
```

So I ran this command to fix it:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Users/CalebKleveter/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin export PATH
```

Am I installing it in the wrong spot?

All gems were working earlier, but I ran this command:

```
rvm use 2.2.3
```

So I am using ruby version 2.2.3, I was using version 2.0.0 before if I remember correctly. Is that the issue?

Comment: set your default ruby version in rvm using this `$ rvm --default use 2.2.3` or to whatever ruby version you want and they try to install gem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue per se, but you might find incompatibilities between old gems and current version of rails.

Run `rvm list` and then set the default to the latest version of rails and update your gems.